# How to map over a list of dates and values and add the values based on unique dates?

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, key

I have this data:

```
data = [['20-01-22', '20-01-22', '09-09-21'],
        [10, 10, 10],
        [12, 10, 1 ]]
```

and I would like to add the value based on the date (ultimately going into an Excel to chart the data).

End result would be like so:

```
data = [['20-01-22', '09-09-21'],
        [20, 10],
        [22, 1 ]]
```

I have tried to pull out the first row and use it as keys to access the next rows, but I am a little stumped.

###### get all the `datetime`s.

```
keys = data[0]
```

```
newlist = [] 
for x in keys:  # returns unique keys
    if x not in newlist:
        newlist.append(x)
```

Can you give me tips on where to go from here - I need to use the keys to access the values and add them.

Comment: You appear to be missing some `'` in your data

Answer (score 2):

If you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['20-01-22', '20-01-22', '09-09-21'],
        [10, 10, 10],
        [12, 10, 1 ]]

pd.DataFrame(data).T.groupby(0, as_index=False, sort=False).sum().T.values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[['20-01-22', '09-09-21'], [20, 10], [22, 1]]
```

Comment: Tysm, this works very well :)